# Talking in shul and churban Europe

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, story-identification

HaRav Yitzchok Sorotzkin said the following [story](http://www.kvodshomayim.org/audio/Stop%20the%20Talking%20in%20Shul%20%20Rav%20Yitzchok%20Sorotzkin%20on%20Kedushas.mp3):

The debitzener himself was present by the Second World War - r"l the holocaust:

*“He was standing on the last transport going to Auschwitz. All of sudden out of nowhere, a lady appeared. This lady started screaming, ‘Jews, Jews, you know why you're suffering so much? Because you speak in the shuls during davening. This is what is causing the churban Europe.’ After she finished this, she disappeared into thin air,"* testified the Debitzener. It was messenger from heaven that came down and told them very clearly that the root cause of churban Europe was due to the fact that they disregarded the sanctity of their shuls in כבוד השכינה.

Does anyone know where the source for this story can be found?

Comment: http://www.ushmm.org/wlc/en/article.php?ModuleId=10006079

Comment: @DoubleAA That link is about Sephardim during the Holocaust.  I don't understand the relevance.  Wrong page maybe?

Comment: @Mike see edit history

Comment: In Antwerp during the war all the shuls were destroyed except the 'Eiseman' shul. This shul was the only ashkenaz or German shul were talking is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

I found this at [eranbenezra.blogspot](http://eranbenezra.blogspot.com/2013/08/blog-post_5467.html). This story was revealed in 1975 by Yehuda Nuezan of Bnei Brak and was confirmed by Rabbi Moshe Stern.

> חורף 1942 בזמן השואה, בתחנת רכבת בעירה ראחוב עומדים קבוצה של יהודים –
>   נגשת אליהם אישה מבוגרת ואומרת יהודים "יהודים! אתם יודעים למה אתם
>   סובלים כל כך הרבה! משום שאתם משוחחים שיחת חולין באמצע התפילה ואת
>   מסדרים את כל עניינכם בבית הכנסת! עד כאן היו דבריה ובתוך שניות נעלמה!
>   (העדות פורסמה לראשונה בשנת 1975 ע"י יהודה נויזן מבני ברק –אישר את
>   נכונות הסיפור הרב הגאון מהמר"מ שטערן שליטא)

Comment: Thanks so much! Would you be to translate the story into english?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah - you translated the story already in the question.